# How to use groovy env. variable in Jenkins to pass through bat command in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: batch-file, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have stage in my jenkinsfile, that executes a bat command:

```
stage ('build'){
  bat '%cd%\\MySimpleProject\\bin\\Execute.bat "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"'
}
```

My batch command requires a parameter that is the current branch in svn.

When I use this:

echo "SVN_BRANCH_NAME is ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"

It would give the value of BRANCH_NAME but if I pass it as param to my batch file, it literally pass ${env.BRANCH_NAME} not the value.

Is their a way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's because all is wrapped in single quotes and groovy won't interpolate the string. Try

```
stage ('build'){ bat "%cd%\\MySimpleProject\\bin\\Execute.bat ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similuar issue, when running `bat` in Jenkins I was not able to get the variable to pass into the command, it would just print the variable as is. e.g. ${env.P4_CHANGELIST} would just print as is, and not have the actual changelist.

**My original approach:**

```
bat 'xcopy "D://CookedBuildInProgress" "\\Path\\To\\File\\CookedBuilds\\Win64_Development_${env.P4_CHANGELIST}" /e /i /s /y'
```

The issue was `${env.P4_CHANGELIST}"` was not passing in the changelist, and instead kept itself blank. As @shipperizer said, its due to being wrapped with the single quote. However, his solution did not work for my need.

**My Solution:**

```
bat """xcopy "D://CookedBuildInProgress" "\\Path\\To\\File\\CookedBuilds\\Win64_Development_${env.P4_CHANGELIST}" /e /i /s /y'"""
```

Triple quotes worked to pass in the variable so it was now `Win64_Development_1234`